# What's meaning of the expression like "Qubit[] => Result"

Tags: programming, q#

In Q#,there are lots of expressions like "Qubit[] => Result".
It can be the type of return result,like this:

```
function TailMeasurement(nQubits : Int) : (Qubit[] => Result) {
        .......
    }
```

Sometimes it can be type of arguements,like this:

```
 operation EstimateFrequency (preparation : (Qubit[] => Unit), measurement : (Qubit[] => Result), nQubits : Int, nMeasurements : Int) : Double
    {....}
```

I think it's a method to declare the type of user-defined. But what's the meaning of it?
After reading the documents, I think it means the left is a detailed explanation of the right.
for example,preparation : (Qubit[] => Unit) means the type of preparation is Qubit[],and the element type of Qubit[]  is Unit. It may like the List in Java?
I just wondered if my understanding is right?

Comment: Off-topic: For specific questions about technical details of a software framework, use official support channels.

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed, as historically this forum does host questions about the quantum languages/frameworks as well as the theory itself. See this other currently open question that is similar to this one, but is about a different framework (qiskit). If this is the policy, all questions related to qiskit and other frameworks that are not related to a general theory question should also be closed for constancy.

Comment: @MarkusHeinrich I agree with Sarah that this is the right place for help with using quantum computing software. Non-quantum-specific ones like stackoverflow don't have enough people who understand the details.

Comment: `Qubit[] => Result` is a type. It is the type of a function that takes a qubit array argument and returns a value of the type `Result`. So `TailMeasurement` is saying it's going to return a thing that is actually a function, and you can then call that function or give it to other methods. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/user-guide/language/typesystem/operationsandfunctions

Comment: @Dr.SarahKaiser You can vote to reopen the question. I did.

Comment: @CraigGidney oh, I got it! Thank you so much! It seems like a basic problem but it really makes me confused so that many codes can't be read correctly. I know it now according to your explanation. Although I have read the document on microsoft.com many times but still can't understand it. You really help a lot. Hopes it also can help others who is the beginner of Q#. Thanks again.

Comment: @Dr.SarahKaiser You're right, I think they should. I am not selective, I'm simply only spending a fraction of my free time on this site. About the policy, it's currently under debate and you are invited to discuss it on meta, e.g. https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/496/would-it-make-sense-for-there-to-be-a-separate-se-site-for-quantum-programming

Comment: @CraigGidney There's certainly no consensus on this topic. Feel free to share your opinion on meta, e.g. https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/496/would-it-make-sense-for-there-to-be-a-separate-se-site-for-quantum-programming